# "To give someone space"

Tags: translation

I was looking for the equal word of "to give someone space" in Chinese and found this :

> 给我一点**空间**。

I'm not sure if 空间 is the correct word though. 空间 means "space" but I think it refers to a visible one.

While the "space" that I mean here is like giving someone some me-time, giving them time to be just alone, or letting them do whatever they like without us being too clingy.

Now, can I still use 空间 to refer to that kind of space?

Comment: Yes, you can. And I think this usage of 空间 origins from English in Hongkong.

Comment: submit ＂space＂ to iciba, find example sentences for 12 types of space, esp. (4)N-UNCOUNT (思考问题、个人成长所需的)时间，余地，空间 with 2 example sentences, submitting "时间，余地，空间" to bkrs will yield more examples, also consider submitting "elbow room" to iciba, get 3 sample sentences including "political elbow room" 政治空间

Comment: For me, it’s more natural to say 別打擾[他] *don’t disturb [him/her]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the expression you had is correct and indeed used in daily life. There are however, some alternatives which you could use

> 请给我一点自由空间
>
> 请给他一些自由
>
> 给我一些自己的时间

Answer (score 2):

In chinese, 空间 also have the meaning of freedom, or letting someone do whatever they like. It does not only mean the visible space.